# Recursive copying folders in C#, is there anyway?

Tags: c#, .net, file, file-io, rename

I look at `System.IO.File.Move`, "move" the file to a new name.

```
System.IO.File.Move("oldfilename", "newfilename");
```

But it not enough for me to using this method.

Infact I want to recursively copy a folder and all of it's subfolders into a new path and change name of these file. anyone could take me a pieces of code?

Comment: To loop each sub-directory more safely and recursively, related topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525090/access-to-the-path-d-recycle-bin-s-1-5-21-494745725-312220573-749543506-41600/34525432#34525432

Comment: This is very similar, but does not change the name of the files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744/best-way-to-copy-the-entire-contents-of-a-directory-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to move a folder:

```
string newDirPath = "E:\\New\\destDirName";
Directory.CreateDirectory(newDirPath);
Directory.Move("D:\\sourceDirPath", newDirPath);
```

If you want to [copy a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744/best-way-to-copy-the-entire-contents-of-a-directory-in-c-sharp):

```
//Create all of the directories
foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath, "*", 
    SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));

//Copy all the files & Replaces any files with the same name
foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*", 
    SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath), true);
```

Comment: Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744/best-way-to-copy-the-entire-contents-of-a-directory-in-c-sharp

Comment: using this command we can access to all folder and subfolders "foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath, "*", 
    SearchOption.AllDirectories))" okey ?

Comment: @MathLover yes, it is.